# Javascript - Optimal Path (Angles)

Tags: javascript, path

I am participating in a racing challenge which requires me to write a script to beat an AI opponent. I am provided with my "Current Position" (X,Y) of the "Target Position" (X,Y) the "Distance" to the next target and the "Angle" (degrees) the vehicle is facing. Each move I am to provide an (X,Y) coordinate of the position I want the vehicle to go and speed (%) i.e. 0% = doesn't move, 100% = full speed.

The track is dynamic each race so nothing can be hard-coded and the AI opponent almost never slows down, instead it's calculating an optimal path to the next target by offsetting the target position.

Currently I have played around with adjusting the speed as it gets closer to the target however I always loose the race as it's simply too slow. I am having a lot of trouble understanding how to offset a target position based on my vehicles current angle to the target and hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I apologise for the crude mock-up

Thanks,

Image: http://i68.tinypic.com/1628txi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to mention that the max speed is provided. So you could get the distance that you will achiev by giving a % to the next step: %/100 * maxSpeed. This way you can determine wheter you go past the targetPoint, and if yes give the exact speed.

Also you should tag this question with physics.

Answer (score 0):

The Max Speed isn't provided in fact no Speed is provided only the following:
 - Player Coordinates (X,Y)
 - Target Coordinates (X,Y)
 - Distance : Between Player - Target
 - Angle : Player Direction to Target

What I need to provide in each move is:
 - Target Coordinates (X,Y) : Direction I want the Player to go
 - Speed/Throttle (%) : 0% - 100%

The vehicle does get progressively faster so the Current Speed/Max Speed is unknown without some calculations. However I am not sure if adjusting the speed is the solution, it's more about hitting the each Target in a way that the vehicle is almost already pointing to it's next target (Like Drifting).